# vectorization running in infinite loop in octave

Tags: octave

I am trying to compute [image: equation] 
 where `h(x) = X*theta, theta is nx1 matrix and X is an mxn and y is also m x 1` matrix. `alpha,m,theta(j) and x(j)(i)` are scalar values. I am trying to vectorize this by below way

```
    theta0 =(X*theta - y)
    theta1 = (X*theta - y).*X(:,2)
    theta0 = sum(theta0);
    theta1 = sum(theta1);
    theta0 = theta(1) - theta0*alpha/m;
    theta1 = theta(2) - theta1*alpha/m;
    theta = [theta0;theta1];
```

where `num_iter=1500` and `m=length(y)` but my code went into infinite loop. my equivalent for loop solution is below

```
     theta0 =0;
     theta1= 0;
     for i = 1:m,
        theta0 = theta0 + (sum(X(i,:)*theta) - y(i));
         theta1 = theta1 + (sum(X(i,:)*theta) - y(i))*X(i,2);
     end
     theta(1) =  theta(1) - theta0*alpha/m;
     theta(2) =  theta(2) - theta1*alpha/m;
```

please let me where I went wrong

Comment: In your previous question you said `y` is of length `m`.  Is it a typo here? As @Sardar said, sizes wouldn’t match if it is of length `n`.

Comment: Btw `for` loop in Octave can never be an infinite loop. If your Octave  got stuck, it may be that you ran out of memory

Comment: @CrisLuengo: sorry it's typo y is mx1 matrix

Comment: my X is 97 x 2 matrix while theta  is  2 x 1 matrix and y is 97 x 1 matrix

Comment: how? my n is 2 right. I did typo previously saying y nx1 but it's mx1

Comment: hi I said first snippet I posted that I tried to do vectorization. second snippet is equivalent for loop code for the 1st snippet. I mentioned it clearly

Comment: that was common for loop for n iterations. it's common for both snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula can be written in a vectorized manner as:

```
theta = theta - alpha/m * ((X*theta - y).' *X).';
```

Comment: what did you add **.'** ? are you transposing whole vector?

Comment: `(X*theta - y)` is transposed to achieve the multiplication with `X` and do the summation using matrix multiplication. After that, the transpose at the end is done to make the dimension of the term in accordance with theta